# React: Prevent Layout Shift in Dropzone When Previewing Uploaded Images

Tags: reactjs, react-dropzone

I'm working on a React project where I'm using a drag-and-drop area to upload images. I'm facing a layout issue: when images are uploaded and previewed, the entire dropzone area shifts or resizes, which I want to avoid. I want the dropzone to maintain its size and position, regardless of the number of images uploaded for preview.

Here's a brief overview of my setup:

1. DragAndDropArea Component: Handles the file drop functionality and uses `react-dropzone`.
2. ImagePreview Component: Displays the image previews.
3. App Component: Manages the state for uploaded images and uses both DragAndDropArea and ImagePreview components.

Despite separating these components and trying various CSS approaches, the dropzone area still changes its size or position when images are uploaded, also did not found similar posts here.

Here's a snippet of my DragAndDropArea component:

```
function DragAndDropArea(props) {
  // ... onDrop logic ...
  
  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <section {...getRootProps({style: dropzoneStyle})}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
        <p>Drag and drop your images here.</p>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Image Preview component:

```
  const ImagePreview = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <aside style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap' }}>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <div style={thumbStyle} key={index}>
          <img
            src={image}
            alt={`Uploaded ${index}`}
            style={imgStyle}
          />
        </div>
      ))}
    </aside>
  );
};
```

And app.js

```
function App() {
  const [uploadedImages, setUploadedImages] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <DragAndDropArea onFilesAdded={setUploadedImages} />
      <ImagePreview images={uploadedImages} />
      {/* Other components */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm looking for suggestions on how to keep the drag-and-drop area's layout static while displaying image previews. Any advice on how to structure the components or style them to achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!